# Applying window.document styles to Polymer 2 child elements

Tags: javascript, css, dom, polymer, polymer-2.x

I am working on a app in which users can build a webpage by dragging and dropping. Some of the elements our users can drop are Polymer2 elements.

Users can also add custom stylesheets to their pages and if they do so, the styles defined in there should affect the Polymer2 elements' children.

Now, I know all if this sort of goes against the way web-components are designed to behave, but I still wonder if it would be possible.

I am very new to Polymer and not quite sure in which direction to look. I've read about mixins, shared-styles and custom-styles, but none seemed to provide a valid approach for my use-case.

Any help is very much appreciated.

**EDIT**

So far I have found one solution to be working but not ideal because `import` will be deprecated in the future:

`/parent-styles.html`

```
<link rel="import" href="../../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
<dom-module id="parent-styles">
    <link rel="import" type="css" href="ref_to_page_stylesheet.min.css">
</dom-module>
```

I can then import this file and use `<style include="parent-styles"></style>`. This at least allows the Polymer element to be styled from the page's stylesheet, but obviously this solution would break as soon as the stylesheet name or location changes, which I am not so happy with.

Answer (score 1):

> There are many options for styling web components. A component that
>   uses shadow DOM can be styled by the main page, define its own styles,
>   or provide hooks (in the form of CSS custom properties) for users to
>   override defaults.

To style a component `<fancy-tabs>` from the outside, you could just use its tag name as a selector:

```
fancy-tabs {
  width: 350px;
}
```

Outside styles always win over styles defined in shadow DOM. But this only gets you so far. What if you want to style the internals of `<fancy-tabs>`? This is where you will have to create style hooks using custom CSS properties.

Example:

```
<!-- main page -->
<style>
  fancy-tabs {
    margin-bottom: 32px;
    --fancy-tabs-bg: black;
  }
</style>
<fancy-tabs background>...</fancy-tabs>
```

Inside the shadow DOM of `<fancy-tabs>`:

```
:host([background]) {
  background: var(--fancy-tabs-bg, #9E9E9E);
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

In this case, the component will use black as the background value since the user provided it. Otherwise, it would default to `#9E9E9E`.

Reference used: [Shadow DOM v1: Self-Contained Web Components](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/primers/shadowdom)

Comment: I think I understand what this example does, but I don't think it solves my problem. Especially because I cannot possibly know which nested elements, and which of their properties would be styled in the page style sheet. I can see some other good uses for this approach.

Answer (score 0):

I worked out some sort of solution by myself. As I already stated in the question, it sort of goes against the web component philosophy of encapsulation. It also relies on link tags which will become deprecated in the future. Worst of all, I haven't done any cross browser testing yet... So:

**USE WITH CAUTION!**

You can use the style module below like this (after importing it):

`<style include="bb-shared-styles"></style>`

```html
<dom-module id="bb-shared-styles">
  <template id="style-template">
    <style id="stylesheet"></style>
  </template>

  <script>
    ((document) => {
      const doc        = (document._currentScript || document.currentScript).ownerDocument;
      const domModule  = doc.querySelector('#bb-shared-styles');
      const template   = doc.querySelector('#style-template');
      const pageStyles = document.styleSheets;
      const styles     = template.content.querySelector('#stylesheet');
      styles.type      = 'text/css';

      
      processStyleSheets();

      function processStyleSheets () {
        for (let index = 0; index < document.styleSheets.length; index++) {
          const sheet = document.styleSheets[index];
          if (sheet.href) {
            // Prefer adding links to parsing CSS rules for better performance
            appendLink(sheet.href);
          } else {
            const rules = sheet.rules || sheet.cssRules;
            if (rules) {
              // For inline styles
              appendRules(rules);
            }
          }
        }
      }

      function appendRules (rules) {
        const len = rules.length;
        for (let index = 0; index < len; index++) {
          const rule = rules[index];
          styles.appendChild(document.createTextNode(rule.cssText));
        }
      }

      function appendLink (href) {
        let link   = document.createElement('link');
        link.rel   = 'import';
        link.type  = 'css';
        link.href  = href;
        domModule.insertBefore(link, domModule.firstChild);
      }

    })(document);
  </script>
</dom-module>
```